# Where to find a list of "universal" Linux binaries?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm looking for the best way to determine if a binary is installed on virtually all Linux systems. Essentially, I'm just interested in determining portability for BASH scripts. How can I know which binaries I can use that will be largely available on all Linux distributions?

Tonight, I'm specifically concerned with figuring out if `strace` is as widely available as something like `grep`. I'd still highly appreciate an answer to the larger question, however.

Comment: You should take a look at the `which` command.

Comment: @Robert: That will only tell you whether a command is available (and in `$PATH`) on the current system.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, the minimum set of features is to a large extent governed by the [Linux Standard Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) specifications, and the related Single Unix Specification and POSIX.

If you write your scripts to follow POSIX, you will be unable to assume you have Bash at all.  Some Linux systems use a shell other than Bash by default, including Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu's `/bin/sh` isn't `bash` by default, but `/bin/bash` is installed by default, and it's the default user login shell.